# Looking for the least expensive way to level Basement floor

Tags: concrete, basement, subfloor, basement-refinishing

How can I level my basement floor, which has a 2-3inch dip in the middle?

Comment: How big is the dip area (small area dent or the whole floor slopes towards the middle?  Is there a floor drain in the middle?  If not, is the dip due to settlement (in which case there would be cracks around the dip where the floor bends?

Comment: Several company's make concrete leveling products. Do a google search.

Comment: Voting to close. The nature of the problem isn't clear and OP hasn't been back.

Answer (score 1):

If there isn’t a moisture problem, I’d use a gypcrete self-leveling compound. Feather to edges and cover entire floor with your final floor finish. (Gypcrete can’t be left exposed. It’s not a walking surface.)

Gypcrete can only be installed to 3”-4” depth, so it would be fine. If there’s a moisture problem, you must take care of that first.